# How to loop through result in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I get the `dataValues` out of the response. I have tried doing `console.log(result.dataValues)` but it returns undefined.

Response

```
[ User {
  dataValues: {
    id: 16,
    user_id: '140235016357535420',
    server_id: '535881918483398676',
    xp: 40995,
    coins: 0,
    createdAt: 2019-03-09T22
    :
    59: 09.216Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-03-09T22
    :
    59: 09.216Z
  },
},
User {
  dataValues: {
    id: 16,
    user_id: '140235016357535420',
    server_id: '535881918483398676',
    xp: 40995,
    coins: 0,
    createdAt: 2019-03-09T22
    :
    59: 09.216Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-03-09T22
    :
    59: 09.216Z
  },
},]
```

Query

```
User.findAll({
    where: {
        server_id: msg.guild.id,
    },
    limit: 2,
    order: [
        ['xp', 'DESC'],
    ],
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        user_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        server_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        xp: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        coins: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }, {});
    /*  User.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };*/
    return User;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like an array of User objects; dataValues is a child of each User. First iterate over the array and get the objects, then extract `dataValues`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
  console.log(result[i].dataValues);
}
```

Using `forEach()`:

```js
result.forEach( 
  (user) => { 
    console.log(user.dataValues);
  }
);
```

Comment: Array.forEach isn't asynchronous. It might only seem that way, depending on what you do in the callback.

Answer (score 7):

**Before render/print you need to transform the Models array into array**

```
const records = results.map(result => result.dataValues)
```

Details:

Out of Model search you've got an array of models like:

```
[ User {
  dataValues: {
    id: 16,
    user_id: '140235016357535420',
    server_id: '535881918483398676',
    xp: 40995,
    coins: 0,
    createdAt: 2019-03-09T22,
    updatedAt: 2019-03-09T22
  },
},
...]
```

Just "map" it like this:

```
const results = await User.findAll();

const records = results.map(function(result) {
            return result.dataValues
        })
```

and You'll get an array like this:

```
[
{
    id: 16,
    user_id: '140235016357535420',
    server_id: '535881918483398676',
    xp: 40995,
    coins: 0,
    createdAt: 2019-03-09T22,
    updatedAt: 2019-03-09T22
},...
]
```

*compact version:

```
const records = results.map(result => result.dataValues)
```

Comment: This converts my array to an object type in node